# How do I call a 3rd party javascript library with emscripten?

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I have a large codebase in C that I want to compile into Javascript using emscripten and run in a browser.  No problem.

I then want to add a 3rd party javascript library and invoke it from the C code using emscripten's mechanisms.

I've added the calls to the 3rd party js library using the EM_ASM construct.  If I compile the C code to html/js files it doesn't see the 3rd party js library.
If I manually edit the html file to add

```
<script src="3rdPartyLib.js"></script>
```

it works great.

How do I make enscripten put the `<script>` tag in there rather than doing it manually?

Comment: I think you can read about JS Module loaders like CommonJS and pass in the "require" function to the C code and load modules from there itself. But overall I feel this isnt required. You should architect your application in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shell file with the flag `--shell-file <path>`. The generated HTML will use that file as a template, so you can include your custom script tag.

From [Emscripten's docs](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-shell-file)

> --shell-file <path>
>   The path name to a skeleton HTML file used when generating HTML output. The shell file used needs to have this
>   token inside it: {{{ SCRIPT }}}.